# NPM dependency issues on a new build server

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, npm, webpack

We recently had to rebuild a Windows build server which we use to build and deploy our websites.

On recreating the server everything builds and deploys apart from an ASP MVC5 website that uses WebPack to bundle and minify CSS, JavaScript, TypeScript and Images, etc.

When building on my local machine, it builds fine (doesn't it always), but on the build server I get the following:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: webpack-config@undefined
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.66.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"5.66.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from css-loader@2.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/css-loader
npm ERR!   dev css-loader@"2.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

The version of Node.js installed is v18.17.0 and the NPM version is v9.6.7 which to my knowledge, is the latest versions (it is not known what versions had been installed on the old machine).

In my simple mind, I have Webpack version 5.66.0 installed and css-loader version 2.1.0 is showing as not compatible with this version.

Now to my question, What is the best way to resolve the above?

My yaml file has the following:

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm web'
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/50 Web/Web
- script: |
    npm install -g webpack webpack-cli --save-dev 
    npx webpack --config $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/50 Web/Web/webpack.config.js --env production
  displayName: 'run webpack'
```

I tried to add the --force and --legacy-peer-deps, to the command and the scripts above, but it did not work.

Thank you.